# How to open and read a file and write specific content to a new file?

Tags: java, regex, read-write

First week learning Java. Apologies for my broken code below. Trying to open a file read it and choose needed contents to write in another file. My file looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTION:
TITILE:
TYPE: image
SOURCE: Library
FORMAT: jpeg 
IDENTIFIER: 120034 
LATITUDE: 40.109580 
LONGITUDE: -88.228378 

DESCRIPTION: 
TITLE: GSLIS 
SUBJECT: 
TYPE: image 
SOURCE: Library 
FORMAT: jpeg 
IDENTIFIER: 120155 
LATITUDE: 40.107779 
LONGITUDE:-88.231621
```

I just wrote two pieces of code, one for open and read, one for match the patterns:

```
package Functions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class readFileLocal {
    private static final String[] String = null;
    private String path;

    public readFileLocal(String file_path){
        path = file_path;
    }

    public String[] openFile() throws IOException{  
        FileReader freader = new FileReader (path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader (freader);

        int numberOfLines = readLines();   
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines]; 

        int i;  
        for (i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++){

            String newLine=new String();
            newLine=null;
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine(); 
            String a = textData.toString();
            while ((textData[i])!=null){
                if (a.startsWith("Identifier: ") || a.startsWith("Latitude: ")||a.startsWith("Longitude:")){
                    newLine.append(a);
                }

                boolean filled1 =Boolean.valueOf(String newLine[0]);
                boolean filled2 =Boolean.valueOf(String newLine[1]);
                boolean filled3 =Boolean.valueOf(String newLine[2]);

                if(filled1, filled2, filled3) {
                       System.out.println(newLine[0]+'|'+newLine[1]+"|"+newLine[2]+"\n");
                }

                }
        }
    textReader.close();     
}


    int readLines() throws IOException{
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader lines = new BufferedReader (file_to_read);

        String aLine=lines.readLine();
        int numberOfLines = 0;
        while(aLine != null) { 
            numberOfLines ++; 
        }  

        lines.close();
        return numberOfLines;
    }
```

}

I also figured how to search a string in the way I wanted with people's help, as shown below:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadLatLong
{

    public ReadLatLong(){

       String line = "IDENTIFIER: 115956 LATITUDE: 40.104730 LONGITUDE: -88.228798 DATE RIGHTS IDENTIFIER: 115956 LATITUDE: 40.104730 LONGITUDE: -88.228798 DATE RIGHTS"; 
        String pattern = "IDENTIFIER:\\s(\\d*)\\sLATITUDE:\\s(\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\sLONGITUDE:\\s(.*?)\\s";

       Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
       Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

       while (m.find()) {
           System.out.println("Image: " + m.group(1)+"|"+m.group(2)+"|"+m.group(3));
       } 
   }
}
```

Now I wonder how to search the whole file to grab all identifier, latitude, longitude, and put them all out like this:
`120034 | 40.109580 | -88.228378 \n`
`120155 | 40.107779 | -88.231621 \n`

This is my main method but I don't know how to write it in a new file either.

```
package readText;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class FileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file_path1 = "F:\\CampusImages.txt";
        String file_path2 = "F:\\CampusImageIDs.txt";

        try{
            ReadFileLocal file = new ReadFileLocal(file_path1);
            WriteFile writeout = new WriteFile( file_path2); //Don't know how to write it in new file.
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(file_path2)));
            String[] arylines = file.openFile();
            writeout.WriteToFile(String.valueOf(arylines));

            int i;
            for (i=0; i<arylines.length; i++){
                System.out.println(arylines[i]);
            }   
       writer.close();  
        }

        catch(IOException e) { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is your programming homework, so I won't give you the exact coding. Unless your input file is empty, otherwise your `readLines()` method will loop forever. if it is not a must, you don't need to count the no. of lines before reading each of them. Here is what you can do:

```
read one line from the file
while the line is not null
    check if the line begins with one of the three identifier you want
    if so, append the line to a string
    if not, do nothing
    if the accumulated string has all three required line, use `ReadLatLong` to do an output
    (simplest way is to use 3 bool flags)
    read another line using the same variable name as at the beginning
end while
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: OK, since RoverMAX has given his coding, I give you another version for you to consider.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestCampusImages {

    static final String file_path1 = "CampusImages.txt";
    static final String file_path2 = "CampusImageIDs.txt";
    static final Pattern pID = Pattern.compile("(?<=IDENTIFIER:)[\\d\\s]*");
    static final Pattern pLAT = Pattern.compile("(?<=LATITUDE:)[\\d\\s-.]*");
    static final Pattern pLONG = Pattern.compile("(?<=LONGITUDE:)[\\d\\s-.]*");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id = 0;
        float latitude = 0.0f, longitude = 0.0f;
        try {
            File inFile = new File(file_path1);
            BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
            File outFile = new File(file_path2);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
            String inLine = textReader.readLine();
            while (inLine != null) {
                Matcher m = pID.matcher(inLine);
                if (m.find()) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(m.group().trim());
                }
                m = pLAT.matcher(inLine);
                if (m.find()) {
                    latitude = Float.parseFloat(m.group().trim());
                }
                m = pLONG.matcher(inLine);
                if (m.find()) {
                    longitude = Float.parseFloat(m.group().trim());
                }
                if ((id!=0) && (latitude!=0.0f) && (longitude!=0.0f)) {
                    out.println(String.format("%d | %f | %f ", id,  latitude, longitude));
                    id = 0;
                    latitude = 0.0f; longitude = 0.0f;
                }//end if
                inLine = textReader.readLine();
            }//end while
            textReader.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }//end try
    } //end main

} //end TestCampusImages
```

This code is good since it allow you to further process the data extract if so required. But it has no validation on the input file. So be careful. If you consider any of the response here is helpful, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: No, this is not my homework. It's just one project I am trying to do and picking up Java at the same time. I learnt a little python at school, and that is the lens I use to understand Java, but my Python is pretty basic too. :-P Anyway, thanks for your clue.

Comment: Sorry about the inappropriate wordings I use. Unreasonable things just happened lately. I recalled when I started up with Java, I once looked up each and every word in a sample code others sent to me with javadoc. If you have time, you may consider looking up statements and their meanings in javadoc. It helps a lot in my case.

Comment: Thanks. I am reading different resources. Something I like to use for learning is other people's code. I like to read definition, sample code, and detailed explanation, in that order I can understand things better.

Comment: I was trying to follow your hint but feel very lame going through. I am still have a few errors marked along the code. Could you please give me some help? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learnt to use the matching part. Thank you very mcuh.

Comment: So if I try to parse a string in this piece of code, like the IDENTIFIER is `My Old House` instead of a number, should I use delimiter `:`. I know how to use simple tools separately but have no idea how to fit them into a piece of complicated code.

Comment: Yes you can. First change the `int id=0;` to `String id;`. Then you can use `startsWith()` to identify the "IDENTIFIER:" line and use `String.split(':')` method which gives you a `String[]`. Second element of which will be your `My Old House`, put it into `id` which is a String now. But don't forget when you write it to output, use `out.println(String.format("%s | %f | %f ", id,  latitude, longitude));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this to read file line by line, and output line by line.  I'm sure there's other ways to do this, just experiment around.

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(yourfile);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream (yourOutputFile);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fout);
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        //Do something; 
        String writeContent = your_code_to_get_write_content(line);
        ps.println(writeContent);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but there was always an error for the line `      fout.println(writeContent);` The error message is: `The method println(String) is undefined for the type FileOutputStream`.